# Enter value to textArea on IE with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that open Internet Explorer browser at specific URL.
I know how to refer to specific elements ant to enter values to textBox (See at the code on the bottom).

But when I used this code on textArea, the data I am enter isn't inserted to the textArea.

PLS help me.

thanks in advance

```
$userNameID = "ctl00_MainContent_login_control_UserName"
$passwordID = "ctl00_MainContent_login_control_Password"

$loginButton = "ctl00_MainContent_login_control_LoginButton"
$phonesID = "ctl00_MainContent_reciSel_TabsContacts_tabFromFile_txtFromFile"
$sendSmsButton = "ctl00_MainContent_btn_SaveAndSave"
$messageBoxID = "ctl00_MainContent_txt_ContentText"
$confirmButton = "ctl00_MainContent_ButtonOk"

$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.visible = $true
$IE.navigate2("myUrl")
while($IE.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

**#this works on this element:**
$IE.Document.getElementByID($userNameID).value = "user name" 
**#this works on this element:**
$IE.Document.getElementByID($passwordID).value= "password"

$IE.Document.getElementByID($loginButton).Click()
while($IE.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

**#Does not work on this element:**
$IE.Document.getElementById($messageBoxID).value = $messageToSend
```